# Detect if my device has internet

Tags: android, networking

I want that my app be able to detect if my device has or not internet connection. I have write this code but it doesn´t work. Here is the code:

```
package mi.internet;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class navegando extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        comprobar();
    }

    private void comprobar() {
        Context context = null;
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(navegando.isOnline(context)== false) {
            new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setTitle("Advertencia").setMessage("No hay internet").setNeutralButton("Close", null).show();
           finish();
        }
    }
public static boolean isOnline(Context ctx) {
    ConnectivityManager connectivity = (ConnectivityManager)ctx.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    if (connectivity != null) 
    {
        NetworkInfo[] network_info = connectivity.getAllNetworkInfo();
        if (network_info != null)
            for (int i = 0; i < network_info.length; i++)
                if (network_info[i].getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED)
                    return true;
    }

    return false;
}
}
```

thank you!

---

Thank you for all the answers. I am novice and I don´t know how I have to use this code. When my application starts I want that if there is not a internet connection a message will display in the screen saying that there is not internet connection and finish the activity.

Tank you again!

Comment: "it doesn´t work" is not a sufficient description of your problem

Comment: Please just edit your question if you have something else to add. Stack Overflow is not a forum, answers are reserved for solutions that solve your problem.

Answer (score 6):

Please try below code . It check Internet connection is present or not in device.

```
public boolean CheckInternet() 
{
    ConnectivityManager connec = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    android.net.NetworkInfo wifi = connec.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
    android.net.NetworkInfo mobile = connec.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);

    // Here if condition check for wifi and mobile network is available or not.
    // If anyone of them is available or connected then it will return true, otherwise false;

    if (wifi.isConnected() || mobile.isConnected()) {
        return true;
    } 
    return false;
}
```

Please add below permission in android manifest file.

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: +1, however I'd be tempted to put that if/else statement into one line to make it super sexy ;)

Comment: You don't need to test the same condition twice. This is poor code. It amounts to return wifi.isConnected() || mobile.isConnected();

Comment: Your edited code won't compile. The final return statement is unreachable. You could always try it my way.

Comment: well, this code can verify that WiFi is enabled. It doesn't verify "internet connectivity". There can be local networks without internet.

Answer (score 4):

```
private boolean isNetworkAvailable() 
{
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager 
          = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return activeNetworkInfo != null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First give permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

and then in your activity

```
private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
    ConnectivityManager cm
      = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo ni= cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return ni != null;
}
```

hope this will work for you